# Hosting multiple html pages in webpack

Tags: webpack, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, html-webpack-plugin

> **My question, simply put is:** How do I host multiple .html pages with webpack?

I am really new to *Webpack* and don't really understand how it works. I've tried reading the documentation to no avail.

I'm creating my first *Outlook Add-In* for *OWA* and *Outlook 2016*. I used the *Yeoman Generator* to scaffold my project with *React* and *TypeScript*. There is also an auto generated config folder with `webpack.common.js` and other *Webpack* files. The `Webpack` dependencies from package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {...
"webpack": "2.3.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0"
}
```

**I'm trying to have my add-in launch an [AsyncDialog](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)** (locally hosted `.html` in a new dialog window, which automatically redirects to the Office 365 sign in page) to connect to sharepoint.
I try to open the dialog at a `dialog.html` page which is in my /src folder along with `index.html` but **I find myself unable to reference anything apart from the default index.html** (referencing `index.html` works but nothing else). The problem persists if I try to navigate to dialog.html via web browser which leads me to believe this might be a *Webpack* problem.

I'm running a `webpack-dev-server` out of localhost and `https://localhost:3000/index.html` works but `https://localhost:3000/dialog.html` does not (displays: `Cannot GET /index.html`).
Possibly relevant information from `webpack.common.js`:

```
const entry = {
    vendor: './vendor.ts',
    app: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './main.tsx',
    ]
};
const output = {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
};
```

Any ideas?

Any and all input appreciated.

Comment: You should be more precise. Where exactly are you unable to add this ref? Anyway, I suggest you to use Visual Studio for developing and debug.

Comment: Funny you should recommend precision, I was updating the question just as you commented :) The reference is in a _React Component_ on the apps landing page, run on a button click. It launches the Dialog just fine, the problem is that nothing loads apart from the `index.html`. I'll be sure to switch to VS I've been using VS Code as per SP Framework guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is a basic requirement which is easily solved with the html-webpack-plugin! [Under "Generating multiple HTML files"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin), I find it surprising I didn't see it sooner, I must've gone through that doc half a dozen times. Hope this helps another noob in the future :/

Thanks to you both for trying to help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

From your Question it looks like that you are unable to access the https://localhost:3000/dialog.html outside of the add-in framework as well. If that is correct then first try to fix that, unfortunately I am not an expert in web packs so won't be able to provide much help there. Let us know if my understanding is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: Yes absolutely that is my main problem :/ I'll get back to you when I get that fixed!